# Where is the JVM program located on MacOS?

Tags: java, jvm

I saw many websites say JRE is included in the JDK, when I download JDK `macOS Arm 64 Compressed Archive`(not the `dmg` file), and unpacked this file, but I didn't find the JRE folder.

And then I found [the oracle seems say](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/install/installed-directory-structure-jdk-and-jre.htm#JSJIG-GUID-F7178F2F-DC92-47E9-8062-CA6B2612D350) the JRE is separated from JDK, so that some people who only want the java run time environment can get what exactly they want. And the JVM is in the `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/`, but there is empty under my `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/` folder, I know probably because I didn't install the `dmg` file for installing JDK.

---

But there must be somewhere that has JVM file, otherwise I won't be able to run my java code, is this correct? I want to know where is the JVM located on my Mac?

The information on my Mac:

```bash
ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-19.jdk/Contents/Home/
LICENSE bin     include legal   man README  conf    jmods   lib     release

ls ~/Downloads/Programs/jdk-17-0-3-1/Home/
LICENSE README  bin     conf    include jmods   legal   lib 

java -version 
java version "19.0.1" 2022-10-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 19.0.1+10-21)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.1+10-21, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Oracle no longer ships/releases a standalone JRE [since Java 11](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/11-relnote-issues.html). The only official package by Oracle (and most other vendors that provide OpenJDK based Java) is the JDK. With `jlink` developers can *build* a "lightweight JDK" with only the parts they want, which is *similar* to a JRE, but more customized. The JDK **includes** the JVM (just like the JRE did).

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

A [Java Virtual Machine (JVM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) is included in every JDK.

Several vendors provide JDK products.

The JDK can be installed anywhere on your Mac. Commonly placed in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`, but not exclusively.

A JRE is a JDK without some development tools.  Little need for JRE nowadays, though some vendors offer JREs.

When in doubt, head to [Adoptium.net](https://adoptium.net/).

## Details

You have a choice of several [Java Development Kit (JDK)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) vendors. They include, in no particular order: *Adoptium, Azul Systems, BellSoft, Amazon, Red Hat, IBM, Oracle, SAP, Microsoft,* and others.

Most of the JDK products shipped by these vendors are based largely, if not entirely, on the codebase of the [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) project.

Some JDK products are free-of-cost, some are commercial  products requiring a fee. Be sure to study the terms.

Some of those vendors offer a [Java Runtime Environment (JRE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(software_platform)#Java_Runtime_Environment) edition of their JDK product. This simply means omitting some of the tools used by software developers. A JRE is meant for end-user machines.

The need for a JRE has nearly gone now that:

- [*Java Applet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet) technology is no longer supported by any browser maker, nor by Oracle.
- [*Java Web Start*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start) is being phased out by Oracle, though an open-source implementation lives on at the [*OpenWebStart*](https://openwebstart.com/) project.

For details, see the 2020-05 white paper by Oracle, [*Java Client Roadmap Update*](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdatev2020may-6548840.pdf)

So nowadays end-users are no longer expected to have a JDK/JRE already installed on their computer. Instead, you are expected to **have a Java runtime bundled within your app**. See the [*jlink*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/282) and [*jpackage*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/392) tools. And understand the [Java Platform Module System (JPMS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System) in Java 9+.

You asked:

> I want to know where is the JVM located on my Mac?

Anywhere.

Apple suggests putting any separate Java installation in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`. This location is usually the default for any JDK installer you obtain from a JDK vendor.

[*IntelliJ*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) IDE can [download and install a JDK](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tips/download-jdk/) in its own location. I don’t recall where.

The [*SDKMAN!*](https://sdkman.io/) utility can download and install a a JDK in its own location. I don’t recall where.

Ditto for [*Homebrew*,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) I believe,  though I’ve never used it.

---

If you feel overwhelmed by all the info and choices, I suggest heading to [Adoptium](https://adoptium.net/) (a group effort by various vendors & the [Eclipse Foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_Foundation)) to download an installer for your Mac. Be sure to choose the edition for your Mac’s chip architecture:  Intel ([x86-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64)) or Apple Silicon [M series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_silicon#M_series) (ARM, Aarch64).